# Can't install pyHook3, pyhk3 for python 3.6 in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pyhook

Before I learned python I had a few scripts in AHK. Now that I am learning python I want to recreate those scripts in python. Doing some searches I found that people used pyhk3 for this and pyhook3 is a dependency for that as seen [here](https://github.com/FunkMastaZ/pyhk3/blob/master/pyhk.py) on line 46. How ever I am having trouble installing them. For pyhook3, only versions 2.7 and 3.5 are available at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHook3/1.6.1) so I checked [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook) for an unofficial version but only pyhook was listed not pyhook3. I also have a second problem. Even if I get pyhook3 for python 3.6 I am having problems installing [pyhk3](https://github.com/FunkMastaZ/pyhk3). After downloading it and navigating to it in comandprompt and issuing the pip command I get this output

```
    pip install pyhk.py

    Collecting pyhk.py
     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhk.py (from 
    versions: )
    No matching distribution found for pyhk.py
```

I checked this website this time for pyhk3 this time but found nothing.

I'm kinda at a dead end so my questions are is there anyway to get these packages to install on python 3.6 and if not is there another way to make hotkey scripts like ahk does? I need something where I type "#email" it will replace that with "example@gmail.com"